# Pivoting Days/Hours in SQL Server From Header to Row Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, testing

I have a list of hours that are under headings from and to.  I need to Pivot those to be by days with from and to headings.  I've tried unpivoting in Excel and Pivot in SQL Server, nothing is working.  Each day is corresponded to a SEQ_NO (Monday = 10, Tuesday = 20, etc.).  The main problem here is getting the start and end times to be in a different view.  Below is the before and after which I want it to look like.  Below is Before and After (what I want it to look like).

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBb17.png)
[After View (what I want it to look like):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO1dq.png)

Before:

```
Name   ║ ID2       ║ Mon Hour Start ║ Mon Hour End ║ Tues Hour Start ║ Tues Hour End ║ Wed Hour Start ║ Wed Hour End ║ Thurs Hour Start ║ Thurs Hour End ║ Fri Hour Start ║ Fri Hour End ║ Sat Hour Start ║ Sat Hour End ║ Sun Hour Start ║ Sun Hour End ║ 
╠══════╬═══════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ John ║ 123456789 ║ 07:45 AM       ║ 11:59 PM     ║ 07:45 AM        ║ 11:59 PM      ║ 07:45 AM       ║ 11:59 PM     ║ 07:45 AM         ║ 11:59 PM       ║ 07:45 AM       ║ 11:59 PM     ║                ║              ║                ║              ║
```

After:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╗
║ SEQ_NO ║ DAYS         ║ DAYS_FROM ║ DAYS_TO  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 10     ║ Monday       ║ 7:45 AM   ║ 11:59 PM ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 20     ║ Tuesday      ║ 7:45 AM  ║ 11:59 PM ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 30     ║ Wednesday    ║ 7:45 AM  ║ 11:59 PM ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 40     ║ Thursday     ║ 7:45 AM  ║ 11:59 PM ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 50     ║ Friday       ║ 7:45 AM  ║ 11:59 PM ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 60     ║ Saturday     ║   ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╬══╣
║ 70     ║ Sunday       ║   ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║  ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╩══╝
```

Comment: @DaleK I tried to put it in that format using this tool but cannot get it look here like it does there. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: @dale I tried a variation of this tutorial. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT [ID2]
, [SEQ_NO] = case 
    when DaysF like 'Mon%' then 10
    when DaysF like 'Tues%' then 20
    when DaysF like 'Wed%' then 30
    when DaysF like 'Thurs%' then 40
    when DaysF like 'Fri%' then 50
    when DaysF like 'Sat%' then 60
    when DaysF like 'Sun%' then 70 end
, [DAYS] = case 
    when DaysF like 'Mon%' then 'Monday'
    when DaysF like 'Tues%' then 'Tuesday'
    when DaysF like 'Wed%' then 'Wednesday'
    when DaysF like 'Thurs%' then 'Thursday'
    when DaysF like 'Fri%' then 'Friday'
    when DaysF like 'Sat%' then 'Saturday'
    when DaysF like 'Sun%' then 'Sunday' end
, [DAYS_FROM], [DAYS_TO] FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        [Name], [ID2]
        , [Mon Hour Start] as [Mon Hour Start1], [Mon Hour End] as [Mon Hour End1], [Tues Hour Start] as [Tues Hour Start2]
        , [Tues Hour End] as [Tues Hour End2], [Wed Hour Start] as [Wed Hour Start3], [Wed Hour End] as [Wed Hour End3]
        , [Thurs Hour Start] as [Thurs Hour Start4], [Thurs Hour End] as [Thurs Hour End4], [Fri Hour Start] as [Fri Hour Start5]
        , [Fri Hour End] as [Fri Hour End5], [Sat Hour Start] as [Sat Hour Start6], [Sat Hour End] as [Sat Hour End6]
        , [Sun Hour Start] as [Sun Hour Start7], [Sun Hour End] as [Sun Hour End7]
    FROM 
        @table
) t 
UNPIVOT 
(
  [DAYS_FROM] FOR [DaysF] IN ([Mon Hour Start1], [Tues Hour Start2], [Wed Hour Start3], [Thurs Hour Start4], [Fri Hour Start5], [Sat Hour Start6], [Sun Hour Start7])
) AS df
UNPIVOT 
(
  [DAYS_TO] FOR [DaysT] IN ([Mon Hour End1], [Tues Hour End2], [Wed Hour End3], [Thurs Hour End4], [Fri Hour End5], [Sat Hour End6], [Sun Hour End7])
) AS dt
where right([DaysF],1) = right([DaysT],1)
;
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If it answered your question, kindly accept the answer as accepted (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in).

Answer (score 1):

You can go for UNPIVOT followed by PIVOT. Please refer to below example. I have only considered monday, tuesday. You can extrapolate the same for remaining days.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(Name varchar(50), ID2 DECIMAL(18,0), [Mon Hour Start] CHAR(8), [Mon Hour End] CHAR(8), 
[Tue Hour Start] CHAR(8), [Tue Hour End] CHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @table values ('John',123456789,'07:45 AM','11:59 PM', '07:45 AM','11:59 PM')

select SEQ_ID, days, [DAYS_FROM],[DAYS_TO] from 
(SELECT Name, id2, 
CASE WHEN LEFT([day],3) = 'MON' THEN 10 WHEN LEFT([day],3) = 'TUE' THEN 20 END as SEQ_ID , 
CASE WHEN LEFT([day],3) = 'MON' THEN 'MONDAY' WHEN LEFT([day],3) = 'TUE' THEN 'TUESDAY' END as [days],
CASE WHEN RIGHT([day],3) = 'END' THEN 'DAYS_TO' ELSE 'DAYS_FROM' end DayCategory,
val FROM @table
unpivot
(
val for [Day] in ([Mon Hour Start], [Mon Hour End],[Tue Hour Start], [Tue Hour End]) 
) as up) as t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(val)
   for DayCategory in ([DAYS_FROM],[DAYS_TO])
)as pvt
```

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
| SEQ_ID |  days   | DAYS_FROM | DAYS_TO  |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     10 | MONDAY  | 07:45 AM  | 11:59 PM |
|     20 | TUESDAY | 07:45 AM  | 11:59 PM |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```